# Xcode 7 unable to find .dylib no existing solution is working for me

Tags: ios, xcode7

No existing solution is working for me, can you help? I've deleted the references and added .dylib again in the build phase (Link Library), added other linker flag (-lz -lsqlite3) but nothing is working.

Here is the error:

***/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib (No such file or directory)***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for previous incomplete ans.

Solution:

I was applying the existing solution in wrong place !!!

The Problem was in facebook sdk...
remove the reference of libsqlite3.dylib (facebook sdk > Targets > Build Phase > link library) [also remove the reference from project navigation]

add "-lsqlite3" in facebook sdk > Targets > Build Settings > other linker flags

If you get any linker error, go to your app (Targets) Build Settings > Enable bitcode > No. (in Xcode 7 it is by default yes)

Comment: If your issue is not solved then why you put this in answer?